# Convert list of array (different dimension) into single array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of arrays. There are 4 one-dimensional arrays and 1 two-dimensional array. I need help in converting it into a single array of arrays. But I am unable to do so because of different dimensions.

For eg: my list looks like this

```
LIST = [
    array([10, 23,  3, 23]),    
    array([10, 23,  3, 23]),
    array([10, 23,  3, 23]),
    array([10, 23,  3, 23]),
    array([
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,],
        [..... -3.83475423e-02, -1.49237230e-01,  5.84510565e-02]
    ])
]
```

Comment: What do you expect?  It's good that you recognize that the different dimensions give problems, but what do you want from us?  Be specific about shape and dtype of the result.  And explain why you need an array instead of the list.

Comment: I don't think you should be mixing the first 4 with the last.  They are too different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Numpy.concatenate(<list_name>,axis=0)
```

If not

```
 Numpy.stack(<list_name>,axis=0)
```

If not

```
 Numpy.array(<list_name>)
```

Comment: How do any of these help with the differing dimensions?

Comment: Numpy.vstack(<list_name>, axis=0).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
a = np.array([10, 23,  3, 23])
b = np.array([10, 23,  3, 23])
c = np.array([10, 23,  3, 23])
d = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]])

>>> np.array([a, b, c, d[0], d[1]])
array([[10, 23,  3, 23],
       [10, 23,  3, 23],
       [10, 23,  3, 23],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7]])
```

Comment: array d has 376 arrays (i.e. columns ) in it. It has to be passed has single entity into the model. To give you a context, last array is of numerical variables and other are of categorical variables.

Comment: The above will still work. The resultant array of size 5 contains 3 arrays of size 4 and two arrays of size 376. As an aside, you probably want to work with a a different datatype if the arrays are different sizes.